# How to perform math calculations in arrays

Tags: python

[image]

My code asks for students weight 3 times at the beginning of the year. 
Then it asks again on the last day of the year. 
And assigns the new weights to the original names. 
However I am having a problem on the calculations as its only calculating the weight of the last student therefore it asks for its weight three times and gives correct calculations based on the last students original weight. 
But I want it to calculate once for each student.

**It should instead be**

for each student its own calculation

Comment: An off-site link to an image of output is not generally acceptable.  Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate for each student, you have to save the entered weights.  Your input loop

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    names_value = str(input('What is your name? '))
    value = float(input('What is your weight in kg? '))
```

executes 3 times -- and each time, replaces the previous name and weight, keeping only the most recent one.  You initialize your list for names and weights to the integers [0, 1, 2] and never change those values.  Try storing them:

```
for student_num in range(3):
    names_array[student_num] = str(input('What is your name? '))
    weights_array[student_num] = float(input('What is your weight in kg? '))
```

Now, you have to *use* those values appropriately -- your later code suffers from the same problem.

Comment: I added an image to my post but it is still doing the same thing

Comment: i dont understand where you would like me to implement that

Comment: I copied your failing code, and supplied replacement code.  What do you "not understand" about my use of your references?

Comment: I copied your failing code in too the full piece of code but I am still getting the same problem (is there a way of me sending you the full code)

Comment: Today is the first day of school :)
What is your name? s
What is your weight in kg? 44
What is your name? d
What is your weight in kg? 55
What is your name? f
What is your weight in kg? 66
s is: 44.0kg
d is: 55.0kg
f is: 66.0kg
Now the year has come to an end :(
What is your weight now in kg? 34
What is your weight now in kg? 45
What is your weight now in kg? 56
['s'] Your weight has decreased by:  10.0 66.0 kg
['d'] Your weight has decreased by:  10.0 66.0 kg
['f'] Your weight has decreased by:  10.0 66.0 kg

Comment: Don't send it to us -- edit it into your original question.  Posting an output dialogue into a comment really doesn't help -- wrong format, wrong place.  If you're having trouble, go back to the intro tour and look for the editing instructions again.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the year start weight to the year end weight, you're using "value", which is currently set to the last student 2-3 lines before.

```
if new_weight_value > value:
        print([names_array[i]],'Your weight has increased by: ', new_weight_value - **value**, 
'kg')
        weights_array[i] = new_weight_value
    elif new_weight_value == value:
        print([names_array[i]],'Your weight has stayed the same')
        weights_array[i] = new_weight_value
    else:
        print([names_array[i]],'Your weight has decreased by: ', **value** - new_weight_value,  
'kg')
        weights_array[i] = new_weight_value
```

Instead of using value you'll need to look up the the value from the `weights_array` like you did with `names_array[i]` by using `weights_array[i]`

Additionally, you can iterate through arrays by using

```
for name in names_array:  #Do
    pass
```

As a rule, you should never need to use range(len()) together.

```
for i in range(len(names_array)):  #Do not!
    pass
```

This way you can avoid having to use the array to lookup values altogether!